# Splitting columns in data frames stored in list

Tags: r

I am new to handling data frames stored in lists and I have the following problem:

Suppose, I have a list of various similar data frames stored inside a list.

A single data frame (df) looks like this:

```
A  B    C    D

a. 0|0. 1|1  10 

b. 0|1. 0|1  20

c. 1|1. 1|0  30

d. 1|0. 0|0  40
```

Output:

```
    A  B_1  B_2 C_1 C_2   D

    a.  0   0.   1.  1.   10 

    b.  0   1    0.  1    20

    c.  1.  1.   1.  0    30

    d.  1.  0.   0.  0    40
```

I can do that for a single data frame:

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(df, 2:3, sep = "|", type.convert = FALSE)
```

however now I have multiple of similar data frames stored inside a list (list of list) and where the indexes of the columns I want to split are not always the same but they can vary.

I wrote something like this :

```
list_splitted <- lapply(list_to_split, function(x) {(str_split(x[[i]],  "|"))})
```

however it seems splitting the columns but all the other columns in all the data frames inside the list are removed.

Any help highly appreciated, thanks

Comment: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: Please share a minimal example of your data, just enough to make your problem reproducible. Use `dput()` for that.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution to my problem:

```
list_ALL2<-list()
for(i in seq_along(list_ALL)){
  list_ALL2[[i]]<-cSplit(list_ALL[[i]], 7:length(list_ALL[[i]]), sep="|", type.convert = F)
}
```

This creates an empty list (list_ALL2) and it fills it with the elements created by applying cSplit on the columns of all the data frames stored in a list (list_ALL). The number of columns to be sorted are from column number 7th till the end of the data frame which can vary. The columns contain the | character which is used here in cSplit as sep argument.